# Qwik, pass a value from child component to parent component

Tags: components, qwik

In the Qwik development framework, there is a requirement to transmit a value obtained from a custom selector (child component) to the parent component, with the purpose of storing said information in an object for later manipulation.

Comment: What do you mean with custom selector? if you have to pass data from parent to child you can use [props](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/overview/#props)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is possible to use a signal in the parent and transfer it to the child through props and change it in the child.